# Many feet - can you tell me my name?

Tags: riddle

Consider the following:

- One foot
- Three feet
- Four feet

These are (in no particular order): my purpose, what I am, and what I have. Wait, one of those is a misspelling!

Can you tell me my name?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My answer shares some of the same logic as the others, but I came up with a different conclusion.

Are you...

> a [footstool](http://sc01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB12wT3IpXXXXXpaXXXq6xXFXXXJ/Round-3-Legged-Wooden-Stool.jpg_200x200.jpg)

One foot

> "what I am" -> A low footstool might be a foot tall

Three feet

> "what I have" -> A footstool can have 3 or 4 feet, typically

Four feet

> "my purpose" -> For feet!

Comment: You got it! Nice job, bullsy.

Comment: Sweet! I loved the misspelling aspect of this puzzle.

Answer (score 33):

Are you a

> White flag

---

One foot

> What I have: The staff of the flag can be a "foot" when planted into the ground.

Three feet

> What I am: The flag could be three feet tall

Four feet

> My purpose: The flag's purpose is to signal a surrender, or forfeit (misspelled as four feet)

Comment: This is a wonderful and creative answer! Unfortunately, not the one I was looking for. +1

Answer (score 22):

Are you a

> Shoelace

---

One foot

> What I have: a shoelace binds a foot inside a shoe

Three feet

> What I am: A shoelace can be three feet long

Four feet

> My purpose: For feet! (four -> for)

Comment: Another great answer! This one fits so well but it's not quite the answer I was looking for. +1

Answer (score 0):

Are you...

> a Quad Walking Cane

One foot

> my purpose => The cane supplies one extra "foot" to the user.

Three feet

> what I "am" => Three feet seems to be a rough height for these, or at least the top hit for an adjustable one lists 36½"- 46½" as its range.

Four feet

> what I have => Quad-walking canes have [four stabilizing points on the bottom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assistive_cane#/media/File:Quadcane.jpg).

Doesn't cover the misspelling, however.